# Export data from SQL Server database to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis, export-to-excel

Following is the error message I get whenever I try to export data from my SQL Server 2008 database to Excel 2007 file (xlsx):

```
Pre-execute (Error) 

        Messages 

        *   Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
             (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

        *   Error 0xc0202025: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
             (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

        *   Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: component "Destination - tblAddress" (49) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
             (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

This happens for any table I try to export. I didn't find any issue with the metadata.

What could be the possible reason? or how to resolve it?

Comment: how are you *exporting* the data? I don't think this is a programming related question as it stands

Comment: Using SQL Server Import-Export. where should I post this question, if you can give some idea?

Comment: possibly on dba.stackexchange.com or superuser.com

Comment: thanks for guiding me here.. I will close this question.

Comment: no problem I just think you may be able to get help faster and of a better quality if you ask on a different site dedicated to such cases

Comment: @mehow I'd keep the question here. DBA is less interested in this type of SSIS question and superuser doesn't even have the SSIS tag

Comment: @Nirman *How* did you determine there was no issue with the metadata? Where did you look and how did you come to this insight? Could you *edit* your question to walk us through how you generated the error. (right click on my database, tasks, export data...)